# What is the difference between cacert, cert and key used in a curl command?

Tags: ssl, curl

In curl, we are providing cacaert, cert and key to use connect to host securely.

I'm not sure whether my below understanding about each of the values is correct?

cacert - certificate provided to the server by a ca authority to verify

cert - certificate provided for a specific client

key  - private key of the client certificate

Also, How these certificates and keys are used in a browser?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming in this shape. You need to first read an introduction on how TLS works, for example with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security ; you would then have an overview of what certificates are and how certificate authorities come into play.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - I have the basic understanding on TLS and with this question i wanted to understande what the cacert and cert in the curl means. If the same can be compared to how it works in browser, that would be great!

Comment: If the server requires the client to provide a certificate you do it with `cert` and `key` options. `cacert` instead is used if you need to verify the server certificate using a specific CA, outside of the default ones. None of them are mandatory, if you want to compare with a browser, rarely you need to use a client certificate, and the browser has a truststore of CAs and you can't force it to use other ones (besides importing them in its truststore).

Comment: Thanks a lot @PatrickMevzek. This answers my question completely.